# MySQL CONCAT performance vs. PHP concatenation performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, concatenation

I have an `SQL SELECT` request with 2 fields:

```
SELECT `a`, `b` FROM `t`
```

(Both `a` and `b` are `VARCHAR(255)`)

I have to concatenate them this way: `a (b)`

I can do it on a DB level:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`a`, ' (', `b`, ')') FROM `t`
```

Or in the PHP script:

```
$result = $resp['a'].' ('.$resp['b'].')';
```

Which way is more correct and efficient?

P.S. I can test it on my own computer, but:

1. Results on different hardware may differ;
2. I want to know pros and cons of both ways so I can apply best practice in my projects.

Comment: What does your own testing tell you? Personally, I think CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT are almost useless and antithetical (unless you're simultaneously doing something else with the data), but others around here love those functions.

Comment: @Strawberry My testing tells me that you should to read all the question (and P.S. part too)

Comment: Utterly irrelevant (from a performance or functionality perspective) under almost any possible scenario.  This sounds like premature optimization.  Personally I would do it in the database, but there might be good reasons for doing this in the application instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you list and explain those reasons? I have asked this question mostly because of this 'hidden knowledge'

Comment: How does your testing come to that conclusion

Comment: If the concatenation is not useful for the SQL query, then do it on the code. Also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171042/224585 and the second answer too.

Comment: @Edu Usage of `CONCAT` in the query is absolutely appropriate. Please can you explain your position?

Comment: @LibertyPaul . . . Databases are designed to work with many rows of repeating data.  Scalar operations within a row just do not (generally) have a significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 6):

If the client and server are on different machines, then you should probably choose the machine with lower CPU usage.

The cost of the concat (either MySQL or PHP) is minuscule compared to the rest of the effort.  I would expect a benchmark to come back with less than 1% difference.  My Rule of Thumb:  Don't worry about an optimization that won't give at least 10%.  Focus on optimizations that give more benefit.

The number of bytes sent in the resultset is about the same in either case, so this is not a factor.

Does the answer for concat apply to other situations?  Maybe, maybe not.  Another example is "Should I sort using MySQL's `ORDER BY` or PHP's `sort()`?  Again, this feels like another "toss a coin" question.  But... There could be a good reason for doing it in SQL:  Suppose you are ordering strings and you are using the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  That is trivial to specify in MySQL. But for PHP, you would have to load some library and figure out how to use it.  (Even so, the performance might be very similar.)